# OMX.ffmpeg.h264.decoder and MediaCodec related error

Tags: android, genymotion, android-mediacodec

An app streams H.264 video and works fine on many devices and simulators.  However, on an Genymotion Android 4.4.2 simulator (Google Nexus 7 2013), the following code **always** crashes the app:

```
try
{
    myMediaCodec .configure(myMediaFormat, mySurface, null, 0);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //no exception has ever been caught here
}
```

The try-catch block is unable to catch the error.  The following is what generated by the crash in LogCat:

```
06-16 23:06:22.749: E/ACodec(4535): [OMX.ffmpeg.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
06-16 23:06:22.769: A/ACodec(4535): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:3813 CHECK_EQ( (status_t)OK,mCodec->initNativeWindow()) failed: 0 vs. -2147483648
06-16 23:06:22.769: A/libc(4535): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0xb77b763d (code=2), thread 4608 (CodecLooper)
```

If I knew this could happen only with the simulator, I would not be worried.  Since I cannot test on every model of Android, I fear this may happen on some other devices. I am wondering if anyone could offer some tips on how to prevent or catch this to avoid crashing the app. I have little understanding of the above LogCat messages.

Comment: It's an assertion failure in the native implementation of MediaCodec.  There are no guarantees other than what the CTS tests exercise, so if Genymotion doesn't pass CTS then basic MediaCodec operations aren't guaranteed to work.  (I don't know if Genymotion does or doesn't.)  Most of the MediaCodec stuff in Grafika doesn't work with the AOSP emulator because the software AVC implementation doesn't support input from a Surface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Can I interpret it as this type of crash does not happen on any physical devices that pass CTS? Also, can I assume that all physical devices use hardware AVC instead of software?

Comment: All you can tell is that they have a better codec than the one in the AOSP emulator. :-)  The CTS tests cover a number of common actions but by no means all that MediaCodec can do.  Since all you're doing at the point of the crash is configuring the codec for H.264, I think it's safe to say that you should not expect a failure there so long as you're passing valid arguments in.

Comment: Thanks.  This is comforting. Out of curiosity, I am wondering why configure crashes the app instead of generating an exception that can be caught.

Comment: The code is encountering a situation that it never expected to have to handle.  I haven't looked at the code to see what specifically it's confused about.  The failing CHECK_EQ means there's a bug in the stagefright library, not an error in your code.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification. I assume there is nothing I can do to prevent the crash.  Hope this happens only with some emulators.

Comment: Maybe its worth noting that only the sign bit is different between the two numbers in 2's complement bit representation.

Answer (score 0):

comment out

```
// videoFormat.setInteger("max-input-size", this.mWidth*this.mWidth);
```

Comment: Could you please add some more information on how this answers the question, please? Thanks...